# Chartjs 4.2.1 ReactJS label cutting overflowX

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chart.js, react-chartjs, primereact

In my react application I have some graphs what when the label is to big the label get cutted, how can I prevent this situation and make the graph smaller

React 18
Chartjs 4.2.1
PrimeReact 9.5.0

Follow the example bellow that is a custom hook to use states to control my chart

Image example bellow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jifMv.png)

```
import { EChartTheme } from '@/enums'
import { numberFormat } from '@/helpers'
import { ChartData, ChartDataset, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js'

interface IUseCharts {
    labelsLeft: string[]
    labelsRight: string[]
    dataSets: IDataSets[]
    fontSizeLabels?: number
    suggestMaxBottomX?: number
}

interface IDataSets {
    label: string
    data: number[]
}

export const useSchedulesChart = ({
    labelsLeft,
    labelsRight,
    dataSets,
    fontSizeLabels,
    suggestMaxBottomX,
}: IUseCharts) => {
    let newData: ChartDataset[] = []

    for (const dataset of dataSets) {
        const newDataset: ChartDataset = {
            barThickness: 15,
            label: dataset.label,
            data: dataset.data,
            backgroundColor: EChartTheme.SCHEDULES_GREEN_BAR,
            datalabels: {
                color: EChartTheme.DATALABEL_COLOR,
            },
            minBarLength: 10,
        }

        if (newData.length == 1) {
            newDataset.backgroundColor = EChartTheme.SCHEDULES_BLUE_BAR
            newDataset.datalabels!.color = EChartTheme.LIGHT_DATALABEL_COLOR
        }

        newData.push(newDataset)
    }

    const data: ChartData = {
        labels: labelsLeft,
        datasets: newData,
    }

    const options: ChartOptions = {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        aspectRatio: 0.8,
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
                align: 'start',
                //@ts-ignore
                onClick: null,
                labels: {
                    boxHeight: 16,
                    boxWidth: 16,
                    font: {
                        size: fontSizeLabels ?? 11,
                    },
                },
            },
            datalabels: {
                color: EChartTheme.DATALABEL_COLOR,
                font: {
                    size: fontSizeLabels ?? 11,
                    weight: 700,
                },
                formatter: (value: number) => {
                    if (value > 0) return numberFormat(value)
                    return value
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                backgroundColor: EChartTheme.TOOLTIP_BACKGROUND,
            },
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                border: {
                    dash: [2, 5],
                },
                stacked: false,
                beginAtZero: true,
                suggestedMax: suggestMaxBottomX ?? 80,
                grace: '10%',
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 10,
                },
            },
            y: {
                grid: {
                    display: false,
                },
                stacked: false,
                beginAtZero: true,
                border: {
                    display: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size: fontSizeLabels ?? 11,
                    },
                },
            },
            secondYAxis: {
                axis: 'y',
                position: 'right',
                grid: {
                    display: false,
                },
                border: {
                    display: false,
                },
                labels: labelsRight,
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size: fontSizeLabels ?? 11,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }

    return { data, options }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can split the labels. The ticks on scale can be an array of strings.